# View returns wrong value for 'conv' function in MySQL5.6

Tags: mysql, navicat

I just have a simple **query**:

```sql
select
    '100000000000000001' AS `flag`,
    length( '100000000000000001' ) AS `flag_len`,
    conv( 131073, 10, 2 ) AS `flag_from_conv`,
    length(conv( 131073, 10, 2 )) AS `flag_from_conv_len`,
    ('100000000000000001' = conv( 131073, 10, 2 )) AS `flag_eq`
```

when I ran that query in Navicat console, I got:

[image]

Everything looks right, doesn't it? But it comes to the problem when **I save that query into a view** and then query it:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED DEFINER = `root`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `testmyview`.`view_conv4` AS select
    '100000000000000001' AS `flag`,
    length( '100000000000000001' ) AS `flag_len`,
    conv( 131073, 10, 2 ) AS `flag_from_conv`,
    length(
    conv( 131073, 10, 2 )) AS `flag_from_conv_len`,(
    '100000000000000001' = conv( 131073, 10, 2 )) AS `flag_eq`;
```

[image]

Do you see that?
`flag_from_conv` results as `1000000000000000`, it looks different from `100000000000000001` and it is equal to `100000000000000001`.

This problem appears in MySQL5.6.50 with Navicat15.0.9. and the `bin` function also has this problem.

This problem does NOT appear in MySQL8.0.

So, How can I get the Correct Value for conv function in a view? My Server version is MySQL5.6.50.

Update:
The Navicat Console returns wrong result, but the MySQL SSH console returns correct result. so i think, this may not be mysql's problem but navicat's?
[image: navicat console]
[image: mysql console via SSH]

Comment: Maybe this is version-specific issue? 5.6.51 shows correct output: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b620ac3dca36447caeb1f828f5a690fd Test something like `SELECT conv( 131072, 10, 2 ), conv( 131073, 10, 2 ), conv( 131074, 10, 2 );`, test `SELECT conv( 131073.5, 10, 2 );`.

Comment: the flag_from_conv only have 16 chars while flag have 18 chars, maybe the column is varchar(16) ?